# How to reload/refresh element with angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new in Angular JS and learning it. I have a div and i want load data on startup with controller but i want reload it again when data has a new record.

index.html

```
<div id="third-content" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <table id="table-class-detail" class="table table-atd table-responsive" ng-init="reloadElement('page001')">
    <tbody><tr><td>Loading...</td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Angularjs 
Module :

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute','controller'])

.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home',{
        controller: 'AtdCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        //templateUrl: 'temp/404.html'
    })
})
```

controller :

```
angular.module('controller',[])

.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function($scope, $http, $log) {

    $scope.getCurrentClass = function($params){
        $interval(function(){
          $http.post('./reloadpage.php',{'temp':$params})
            .success(function(data){
                $("#table-class-detail tbody").html("<tr><td>Name:</td><td>"+data.name+"</td></tr> <tr><td>Code:</td><td>"+data.code+"</td></tr>");
            })
            .error(function(error){
                $log.error(error);
            })
        },1000);
    }
}])
```

reloadpage.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$temp = $data->temp;
$records = array();
$result = $this->currentClass($temp);
if(!empty($result)){
    $records = array('name' => $result->name,'code' => $result->code);
}else $records = null;
echo json_encode($records);
```

I follow tutorial form this [site](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/refresh-div-angularjs-interval/)  it's not working, i got an error `ReferenceError: $interval is not defined`

Can anyone help me ? How to reload/refresh element on `table-class-detail tbody`

Comment: Try to include your code with `$interval` with it so that we can see the problem clearer.

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: Thanks. I have also updated the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error mentioned `$interval is not defined`, it hints that you forgot to inject `$interval` into your controller/service. Something like this:

```js
angular
  .module('controller',[])
  .controller('IndexCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$log', '$interval', // inject $interval here...
    function($scope, $http, $log, $interval) { // and here...

      $scope.getCurrentClass = function($params) {
        $interval(function() { // ... so that you can use it here
          $http
            .post('./reloadpage.php',{
              'temp': $params
            })
            .success(function(data) {
              $("#table-class-detail tbody").html("<tr><td>Name:</td><td>"+data.name+"</td></tr> <tr><td>Code:</td><td>"+data.code+"</td></tr>");
            })
            .error(function(error){
              $log.error(error);
            })
          }, 1000);
        }
      }])
```

PS: When you have finished the tutorial, pay a visit to [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) on best practices on AngularJS :)

Comment: still have some error ReferenceError: $interval is not defined

Comment: @FebryFairuz did you inject it properly? It should be injected in the function too

Comment: i inject it, but now i got error like this TypeError: $interval is not a function

Comment: @FebryFairuz that's strange. Check my updated answer for a clearer picture (you have to inject into two places). Otherwise, could it be `$interval` is also being used in other controller?

Comment: i follow your new update, there's no error but does not display any thing. *blank

Comment: @FebryFairuz check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PubWVkGrj4g5Dnnvq1nJ?p=preview) for a proof of concept

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98051/discussion-between-park-soon-wai-and-febry-fairuz).

Answer (score 2):

As Park said, you need to inject $interval in your controller or provider, but additionally, you shouldn't use jQuery to manipulate the DOM like that.

You should rather put something like this in your html:

```
<tbody ng-if="loading">
    <tr>
        <td>Loading...</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody ng-if="!loading">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ code }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.name = null;
$scope.code = null;

$scope.getCurrentClass = function($params){
    $http.post('./reloadpage.php', {'temp': $params})
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.name = data.name;
        $scope.code = data.code;
        $scope.loading = false;
    })
    .error(function(error){
        $log.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Upvote for mentioning usage of `jQuery` in controller

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the controller '$interval' parameter must be used for which you have to pass $interval into your controller **angular.module('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval)**